# How to store historical correlation matrices?

Tags: postgresql

Every day we calculate the correlation between ~40 different financial instruments and want to be able to store them in our PostgreSQL database. What would be the best way of storing these values?

We would prefer to have one table that includes all of this information instead of one table for each instrment's correlation with the rest. We were thinking of having each column be the correlation between an instrument and another say [corr(a,b), corr(a,c), corr(b,c)] but this looks would cause issues when we need to access the values if new instruments are added.

Are there any typical ways this is done?

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to use these numbers? Postgres supports the [ARRAY data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/arrays.html)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I think there'll also be a time component (day? hour? minute?...), so @RohitGupta's solution (with added time component) is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the advanced features, you can create a table with rows like this.

- AutoIncrement Key
- Instrument A Id
- Instrument B Id
- Correlation between A and B

Comment: Seems like the best (only?) way forward - but you're missing a time component - these correlations will vary day-to-day, hour-to-hour, even minute-to-minute so any model will have to take account of this - see my comment under the OP's question.